# unable read output from lsm9ds0_acc_mag device driver

Tags: c, driver

I am unable to find a way to read the output values of the sensors from **lam9ds0** driver 
https://github.com/erlerobot/kernel_lsm9ds0/tree/master/i2c

The driver code is available in the above link named **lsm9ds0_acc_mag.c**

Anyone familiar with device driver coding, please help me to get the output values. I am new to device driver concepts.

I have tried assembly language but that doesn't suit my project requirement.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? The one you linked is the driver. Once you have build it on your kernel you should find some files under `/sys`. To read data from your sensor you have to read from that files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever this lsm9ds0_acc_mag driver gets installed, it creates corresponding event files under the directory */dev/input/* with a file name **eventx** ( where x can take any integer value starting from 1).

Reading */dev/input/eventx* this file you will get the accelerometer values in X Y and Z directions

I used the following code

```
#define ACCELEROMETER "/dev/input/event2"
struct input_event event;

U32 u32X;
U32 u32Y;
U32 u32Z;

void getCaliberate()
{
    U16 fd;

    ssize_t ret;

    fd = open(ACCELEROMETER, O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to open /dev");
    }

    while(ret=read(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event)))
    {
        if (ret != -1)
        {
            if (event.type == EV_ABS)
            {

                printf("type = %d\t", event.type);

                if (event.code == 0)
                    u32X = event.value;
                if (event.code == 1)
                    u32Y = event.value;
                if (event.code == 2)
                    u32Z = event.value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Read failed\n");
        }
    }
```